# Matrix representation of transformation defined on creation operators - Bogoliubov transform

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, quantum-information, linear-algebra

In [this paper by Alba Cervera-Lierta](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.07112)  the following transformation is performed:

$$
a_k=u_kc_k+iv_kc^\dagger_{-k} \\
a^\dagger_k=u_kc^\dagger_k-iv_kc_{-k} 
$$

where $c_k$ and $a_k$ represent annihilation fermionic operators and $u_k$, $v_k$ are mere constants. According to the article, the gate (or matrix) that performs this operation is given as:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 u_k & 0 & 0 & iv_k \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0&0&1&0 \\
iv_k &0&0&u_k
\end{pmatrix}
$$

but why is it so? How do we translate the transformation defined on the operators to a matrix acting on kets?

Comment: Are these equations (13) and (14) in the paper? It seems to me that equation (13) is different from what you wrote, since they mix $b_k$ and $c_k$. Also, it seems to me that in the paper $a_k^\dagger$ is not $(a_k)^{\dagger}$. Could it be a typo in the paper?

Comment: @Stratiev yes, I believe it's a typo.  In no other reference do they mix the operators. And yes, I quotes thise equations from the paper. Simply didn't write the cuisine and sine to leave it more simple